# How to browse audio/sound from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I am creating an audio application where there are two buttons named

- Record an audio
- Browse an audio

When the user click on the first button he can record audio. This has been implemented.

When the user click on the second button he can browse for an audio /sound which is already present in the iPhone library. I am getting confused how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

use [iPod Library Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1) to fetch the media items.